How to correctly replace an element in a pd.Dataframe with a list?
I have a simple pandas Dataframe like this:
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        0: [
            "Setup",
            "Dissection",
            "Specimen Removal",
            "Closure",
        ]
    }
)

I want to replace the values in column 0 with colour values, like this:
colours = {
    "Setup": [0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765, 1.0],
    "Dissection": [0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.1568627450980392, 1.0],
    "Specimen Removal": [
        0.9686274509803922,
        0.7137254901960784,
        0.8235294117647058,
        1.0,
    ],
    "Closure": [0.6196078431372549, 0.8549019607843137, 0.8980392156862745, 1.0],
}

test_df.replace(colours)

But running this gives me an error:
File ~/.venv/fastai/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py:729, in Block.replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, mask, using_cow)
    725 elif self._can_hold_element(value):
    726     # TODO(CoW): Maybe split here as well into columns where mask has True
    727     # and rest?
    728     blk = self._maybe_copy(using_cow, inplace)
--> 729     putmask_inplace(blk.values, mask, value)
    730     if not (self.is_object and value is None):
    731         # if the user *explicitly* gave None, we keep None, otherwise
    732         #  may downcast to NaN
    733         blocks = blk.convert(copy=False, using_cow=using_cow)

File ~/.venv/fastai/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/array_algos/putmask.py:56, in putmask_inplace(values, mask, value)
     54         values[mask] = value[mask]
     55     else:
---> 56         values[mask] = value
     57 else:
     58     # GH#37833 np.putmask is more performant than __setitem__
     59     np.putmask(values, mask, value)

ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 4 input values to the 1 output values where the mask is true

What am I doing wrong?

You can use map
test_df.map(colours.get)

Output:
                                                   0
0  [0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.70...
1  [0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.15...
2  [0.9686274509803922, 0.7137254901960784, 0.823...
3  [0.6196078431372549, 0.8549019607843137, 0.898...

If you have different dictionaries per column you could use apply + map:
# {column_name1: dictionary1, col_name2: dictionary2}
dic = {0: colours}

test_df.apply(lambda x: x.map(dic.get(x.name, {}).get))

Or a loop:
dic = {0: colours}

for col in test_df:
    if col in dic:
        test_df[col] = test_df.map(dic[col])

Output:
                                                   0
0  [0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.70...
1  [0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.15...
2  [0.9686274509803922, 0.7137254901960784, 0.823...
3  [0.6196078431372549, 0.8549019607843137, 0.898...

why did it fail?
map takes a callable as input, and thus replaces each cell by the output of callable(cell_content) (which if why you need to use colours.get). In contrast, replace recognises that this is a dictionary and uses a different method to replace the values.
Internally this is:
putmask_inplace(blk.values, mask, value)

which does a boolean assignment:
values[mask] = value

However, while this works well if the assigned values are scalars, this will fail if you have lists since pandas/numpy with consider it as extra dimensions.

OP need replace column 0, not all data like in your answer

Then the same thing per column can be done (test_df[0].map(colours)), but their original approach is a global replace (test_df.replace(colours)), thus I provided what matches that.

Actually I go need to replace all data, not just one column. Thanks. Could you elaborate more on why replace won’t work?

@KG do you meant that you have different dictionaries per column? I updated the answer to provide an approach for this case

You can use Series.map column 0 - if not match get NaNs:
test_df[0] = test_df[0].map(colours)

print (test_df)
                                                   0
0  [0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.70...
1  [0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.15...
2  [0.9686274509803922, 0.7137254901960784, 0.823...
3  [0.6196078431372549, 0.8549019607843137, 0.898...

If need original value if no match:
test_df[0] = test_df[0].map(colours).fillna(test_df[0])

